# Possible to override VB.NET root namespace?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

VB.NET automatically prefixes the root namespace set in the project properties to the namespace of each class. This is different from C#, where the full namespace must be declared each time.

Is it possible to override this behaviour, creating a namespace outside of the root namespace?

Comment: This problem is solved in VS 2012. See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/17360357/233095

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to escape root namespace in VB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311099/is-there-a-way-to-escape-root-namespace-in-vb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just need to set a blank namespace in the project properties dialog and then set namespaces within each source file using Begin/End Namespace commands.

From VS2012 onwards it's possible to get around this, see [stackoverflow.com/a/17360357/233095](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17360357/233095)

Answer (score 5):

Defining the default for the project as blank and then taking total control in each class allows you to do what c# does. However certain project types (Library I believe) do not allow you to change the default namespace to blank.

Use of the Global keyword does not allow you to jump out of the root namespace either:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16czfx55.aspx

Comment: According to the [latest MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dx91cw5(v=vs.120).aspx): *The Global keyword can also be used in a Namespace statement. This lets you define a namespace out of the root namespace of your project. For more information, see the "Global Keyword in Namespace Statements" section in Namespaces in Visual Basic.*  See Shimmy's answer...

Answer (score 5):

They now implemented [it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/484455/allow-escaping-root-namespaces-in-vb):

```
Namespace Global.MyNamespace

End Namespace
```

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 4):

You can change the namespace of the entire project by going to properties on the project.
else you will have to have a empty root namespace and set the name space in each file with the

```
Namespace test
    class.....
End Namespace
```